# How do you add sticky headers to Blazorise DataGrid?

Tags: datagrid, blazor, blazorise

Recently I had a request to add Sticky Header Functionality to a DataGrid in one of my Blazor Server Projects. I am using Blazorise and didn't see any existing features for sticky headers and found limited information online so I figured I'd document my solution.

Answer (score 3):

I will preface my answer with the fact that this solution was built for chrome and may need to be tweaked for different browsers.

To start I added a sticky-header class to my site.css file:

```
.sticky-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

    .sticky-header::before {
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 1px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1px;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .sticky-header + .sticky-header::after {
        content: '';
        width: 1px;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: -1px;
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

A couple of notes about the css. `top` is set to 0 to set the headers to the top of the screen and `z-index` just needs to be set to a higher index then the surrounding elements so that it will stay in front of the other elements.

Additionally I noticed that `position: sticky` got rid of my borders and as a result I utilized the `::before` and `::after` pseudo classes to help act like a internal border but this part of the code isn't necessarily required for sticky headers to work.

Once you have the above css, you will want to add it to your DataGrid. For Each DataGridColumn that you define in the DataGridColumns section you will want to add the following code:

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGridColumns>
      <DataGridColumn HeaderCellClass="sticky-header" TItem="TEntity" Field="@nameof(TEntity.SomeProperty)" Caption="Some Caption" />
   </DataGridColumns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I guess that Sticky headers, means that you have scrollbars to. Have did you achive that? I can't get scroll bars to appear for my datagrid

Comment: Did it work for someone? I added it but it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try ensuring other properties are turned off and you should see the change in the accepted answer.
No scrollbar appears but the headers does float there. Resizable=false  Responsive="false"